# How to use lcov test coverage tool with Hudson continuous integration?

Tags: hudson, code-coverage, lcov

In my environment developers use lcov from command line when working with source code's module tests. 
I would like to know if there is a way to easily add reports from lcov to Hudson's builds? I would ease and automate the whole procedure of gathering test source code coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to publish the generated HTML reports along with your job/builds, have a look at the htmlpublisher plugin: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/HTML+Publisher+Plugin

This allows you to specify multiple html directories and index files to be made accessible from the job or build page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [xUnit Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/xUnit+Plugin). I found the info in [this thread](http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/using-hudson-with-C-boost-displaying-metrics-td385389.html). It has more information for using Hudson to build cpp projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, gave me good starting point to what I am going to do.